# How can I select 12 months with highest value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I've got a problem with SQL query to make a chart in Python.

I want to make 12 rows for each month with highest value of deaths.
Table look like this:

[image]

And the values are for each month from 2021.

I am at this moment

Table one:

| Year | MonthName | total_deaths |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5436581 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5429544 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5422092 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5414213 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5406818 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5392790 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5386664 |
| 2021 | grudzień | 5377197 |

Grudzień is December, and there are values for all of the months.

Expected output:

| MonthName | total_deaths |
| --- | --- |
| January | MAX value of deaths |
| February | MAX value of deaths |
| March | MAX value of deaths |
| April | MAX value of deaths |
| May | MAX value of deaths |
| June | MAX value of deaths |
| July | MAX value of deaths |
| August | MAX value of deaths |
| September | MAX value of deaths |
| October | MAX value of deaths |
| November | MAX value of deaths |
| December | MAX value of deaths |

What I have tried

```
SELECT 
t.Year,t.MonthName,d.total_deaths
FROM dbo.Dim_time as t
INNER JOIN dbo.Deaths as d on t.ID_Date = d.ID_Date
where t.Year=2021
order by total_deaths DESC
```

And don't know how to select it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please elaborate on "12 rows for each month with highest value of deaths" do you mean one day with the highest value or the total of all for each month or the 12 highest days given all months regardless of month (like 12 might be in one month) etc.?

Comment: Also please include the table definitions for each table so we can do the join properly

Comment: I edited your question to give some guidance on what we would look for

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
SELECT t.MonthName, MAX(total_deaths) as total_deaths
 from dbo.Deaths as d 
inner join dbo.Dim_time as t on d.ID_Date = t.ID_Date 
where t.Year = 2021 
GROUP BY MonthName 
order by total_deaths asc
```

And it looks like this:

| MonthName | total_deaths |
| --- | --- |
| styczeń | 2216314 |
| luty | 2530716 |
| marzec | 2815659 |
| kwiecień | 3180238 |
| maj | 3550000 |
| czerwiec | 3947020 |
| lipiec | 4217383 |
| sierpień | 4519157 |
| wrzesień | 4782941 |
| październik | 4999871 |
| listopad | 5215558 |
| grudzień | 5436581 |

Comment: In your question there is no mention at all about 2 tables, just one table. So it was impossible for us anyway to give you a correct solution since you did not provide us with enough information. Anyway I am glad you found a solution

Comment: I am sorry man, that's my fault ;/ Next time i will be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want from each year, from each month, the highest total_Deaths ?

If that is correct then you need a simple group by

```
declare @one table (year int, monthname varchar(50), total_deaths int)
insert into @one values (2021, 'december', 10), 
                        (2021, 'december', 20), 
                        (2021, 'december', 30),
                        (2021, 'november', 40), 
                        (2021, 'november', 60), 
                        (2021, 'november', 50),
                        (2020, 'december', 15), 
                        (2020, 'december', 25), 
                        (2020, 'december', 35)

select one.year, one.Monthname, max(one.total_deaths) as total_deaths 
from   @one one
group by one.year, one.Monthname
```

the result is

```
year    Monthname   total_deaths
2020    december    35
2021    december    30
2021    november    60
```